# Eclipse - Run in Debug Mode fails

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, spring-boot, ubuntu

I am trying to run my Spring Boot application in debug mode (the normal run works fine), but it fails. I have tried to switch ports, I have killed all Tomcat processes and generally I have spent a lot of hours trying to solve it unsuccessfully.
I work on Ubuntu. My JDK is 1.8.0_292.

The output is the following :

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-9999]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:265) [spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:208) [spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297) [spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145) [spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) [spring-context-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.createChildManagementContext(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:193) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.afterSingletonsInstantiated(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:156) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:781) [spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) [spring-context-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) [spring-context-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at com.intracom.iot.IotDashboardApplication.main(IotDashboardApplication.java:54) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1020) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key protection  algorithm not found: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Encrypt Private Key failed: unrecognized algorithm name: PBEWithSHA1AndDESede
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:116) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:87) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:225) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:591) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1018) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: Key protection  algorithm not found: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Encrypt Private Key failed: unrecognized algorithm name: PBEWithSHA1AndDESede
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.setKeyEntry(PKCS12KeyStore.java:677) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineSetKeyEntry(PKCS12KeyStore.java:577) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.security.KeyStore.setKeyEntry(KeyStore.java:1140) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.getKeyManagers(JSSEUtil.java:257) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:114) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Encrypt Private Key failed: unrecognized algorithm name: PBEWithSHA1AndDESede
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.encryptPrivateKey(PKCS12KeyStore.java:921) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.setKeyEntry(PKCS12KeyStore.java:614) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: unrecognized algorithm name: PBEWithSHA1AndDESede
    at sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.get(AlgorithmId.java:448) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.mapPBEAlgorithmToOID(PKCS12KeyStore.java:938) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.encryptPrivateKey(PKCS12KeyStore.java:895) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    ... 35 common frames omitted

2021-06-01 17:37:56.837  INFO 24949 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-06-01 17:37:56.854  INFO 24949 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-06-01 17:37:56.858  WARN 24949 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [cluster-ClusterId{value='60b6463775b3006175ad2ce5', description='null'}-10.124.162.77:27017] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
 com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.waitForSignalOrTimeout(DefaultServerMonitor.java:224)
 com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.waitForNext(DefaultServerMonitor.java:205)
 com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:153)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-06-01 17:37:56.859  WARN 24949 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [pool-2-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-06-01 17:37:56.887  INFO 24949 --- [  restartedMain] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-06-01 17:37:56.888  INFO 24949 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5b4fb46e: startup date [Tue Jun 01 17:37:54 EEST 2021]; parent: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@24657b48
2021-06-01 17:37:56.895 ERROR 24949 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 9999 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 9999, or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Are you using any encryption/decryption during startup? Maybe for DB or some other thing.It says the encryption is not recognized and key protection algorithm in not found

Comment: Are you trying run your app in a separate  tomcat container? Or you're using the embedded tomcat provided by spring boot?

Comment: @Umeshwaran as far as I know, no.

Comment: @RahulDey I'm using the embedded tomcat.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using, down to the patch level? Looks like https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8242565 .

Comment: @MiltosDimitriadis Are you connecting in HTTPS mode.

Comment: @nitind it's 1.8.0_292

Comment: @Umeshwaran yes

Comment: @MiltosDimitriadis Then it is the issue with JDK. See my answer . Try upgrading or downgrading the JDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be an open issue in JDK 8 . Please see the below link .

https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/941

Issue reported for JDK 8u292 , but it is working in earlier versions( JDK 8u282 ) and newer versions (JDK 9+).

Try downgrading/upgrading the JDK based on your need.

Comment: Yes, I changed the JDK and everything is OK! Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped :)